# Android Studio: Is there a "newline-and-insert" function in string.xml editor?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-resources

I want to do like this:

```
<string-array name="animal-array">
  <item>Dog</item>
  <item>Cat</item> <== 1. Hit Alt+Enter or something
  <item>|</item>   <== 2. then insert this line and move cursor ("|" is the cursor)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just place the cursor in-between `<item>|</item>` and use a shortcut `Ctrl+D.`